# Multilayered-LIST-to-ARRAY-transformation in R and any better way than using loops

Tags: arrays, r, list

Looking for the smartest and shortest code to solve the following issue in R. Two non-proper solutions are provided...

```
#Generating a multi-layered list
m      <- matrix(1:50, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
mList  <- list(m[1:5,], m[6:10,])
mList

#Transforming list to array: Option one
mArrayOne <- array(c(mList[[1]], mList[[2]]), dim = c(5,5,2)) 
mArrayOne

#Transforming list to array: Option two
mArrayTwo <- array(numeric(), dim = c(dim(mList[[1]]), length(mList)))
for(i in 1:length(mList)){mArrayTwo[,,i] <- mList[[i]]}
mArrayTwo
```

Any hint is welcome - thanks...

Comment: You can use `unlist` ie `array(unlist(mList), dim = c(5,5,2))`

Comment: Woop woop ;-)...that's exactly what I was looking for...thanks a lot @akrun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just `unlist` the `list` and create the `array`

```
array(unlist(mList), dim = c(5,5,2))
```